# How to populate an array inside another array while iterating a string?

Tags: php, arrays, ajax, laravel, loops

The short: I need to create a looping that is going to populate some arrays inside a master array while iterating a string. (the looping need to "copy" this array based on a rowCount(if it is 100 then it makes 100 arrays, if it is 3 then it makes just like that)

```
$insertData = array(
    array('column_name'=> $obj->{'row1'}->{'column_name'}),
    array('column_name'=> $obj->{'row2'}->{'column_name'}),
    array('column_name'=> $obj->{'row3'}->{'column_name'}),
);
```

The long:

1. I create a string on jquery with for looping
2. I convert this string to json
3. I send a json to a laravel controller
4. Laravel controller gets json and convert with `json_decode($data)`
5. Laravel multiple insert use this last var to insert all the data using the `$insertData` array

the code is allready runing, but if a manually write 100 arrays it is going to save 100 rows even if ajax has only 3 rows, that why I need a function that creates exctly the number the rows ajax gives.

Im trying something like that but it is working and acting like a string, not like a muldimensional array

```
<?php

function createRow($counter) 
{
    $array = array(
        "colum_name" => "'column_name'=> $ obj->{'row".$counter."'}->{'column_name'}",
    );

    return $array['colum_name'] . $counter;
}

$insertData = array();

for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    array_push($insertData, createRow($i));
}

print_r($insertData);
```

and finally the laravel multiple insert

```
\App\MyApp::insert($insertData);
```

Answer (score 0):

put array in the insertData not string will make it works.

```
function createRow($counter)
{
    array('column_name'=> $obj->{'row' . $counter}->{'column_name'});
}

$insertData = array();
for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++){
    $insertData[] = createRow($i);
}
print_r($insertData);
```

Comment: but that way I lost the iterating on 'row1', i need row1, row2, row3 etc